# Async function to crreate dataURL

Tags: javascript, jpeg, onload

I'm trying to create a JavaScript function that will return a dataURL from a JPEG. This function is intended to be called multiple times in the creation of a pdf document in a Vue.js application.
The following is code I've managed to cobble together from various web sites in seeking code examples for jsPDF use.

```
async loadImg (url) {
    var dataURL = null
    var toDataURL = async function (url) {
        var img = new Image()
        img.onError = function () {
          alert('Cannot load image: "' + url + '"')
        }
        img.onload = async function () {
          var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
          canvas.height = this.naturalHeight
          canvas.width = this.naturalWidth
          context.drawImage(this, 0, 0)
          dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')
          console.log('onload ' + dataURL)
        }
        img.src = url
    }
    await toDataURL(url)
    console.log('end of function ' + dataURL)
    return dataURL
}
```

I've tried using a callback approach, but no matter how what I've done I ultimately end up in the same state the console shows the 'end of function' as a null and then a few milliseconds later the onload remark shows up with a long string, which I assume is the dataURL of the graphic (jpg)

OK I thought async / await construct was the same as using promise.. but just to be on the safe side I rewrote my code using promise

```
toDataURL (url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var img = new Image()
    img.onError = function () {
      reject(Error('Cannot load image: "' + url + '"'))
    }
    img.onload = async function () {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
      canvas.height = this.naturalHeight
      canvas.width = this.naturalWidth
      context.drawImage(this, 0, 0)
  resolve(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'))
    }
    img.src = url
  })
}

// in the function to create the pdf
imageData = toDataURL(url).then(function (response) {
  console.log('Success!', response)
}, function (error) {
  console.error('Failed!', error)
})
}
```

There are three jpgs that the main is trying to include in the pdf

In the console I see:

```
Report.vue?./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options:277 Promise {<pending>}
Report.vue?./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options:277 Promise {<pending>}
Report.vue?./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options:277 Promise {<pending>}
Report.vue?./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options:284 841.89 595.28
Report.vue?./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options:272 Success! data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD/2wBDAQMDAwQDBAgEBAgQCwkLEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBD/wAARCALaBEcDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHgAAAAcBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIDBAUGBw ...

There are two additional Success! data:image/ ...
```

My interpretation is while the results are different in that I get a promise object, which is pending then I get the image data. I'm still no further ahead.

Comment: where is the Promise wrapper?

Comment: `imageData` is just going to be the Promise; you get the result _inside of your callback_. I think what you're missing is showing how you're trying to use `imageData`, which is the part in error. You either need to use the result inside of your `then` callback or have the consuming function use `await`

Comment: Got it-- Thanks!! I solved my problem and now have a working application that puts images onto a pdf page. My code is at https://github.com/djbristow/RAILS